# reverse some text in cell selected - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm rooky for VBA. I have some problem about reversing my data on **VBA-Excel**. My data is "**3>8** , **6>15** , **26>41** (each data on difference cells)" that i could reverse "3>8" to "8>3" follow my requirement by using function reverse. But i couldn't reverse "6>15" and "26>41" to "15>6" and "41>26". It will be "51>6" and "14>62" that failure, I want to be "15>6" and "41>26".

*Reverse = StrReverse(Trim(str))*

Help me for solve my issue please and thank for comment.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Comment: can be done with Excel formula too `=Right(A1,Find(">",A1))&">"&Left(A1,Find(">",A1)-1)`

Comment: Reverse does what it says on the tin, literally.
Excel does not understand that you think 15 is a number, it reads 1 and 5 and then reverse it to 51. Use @Slai method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to find the position of the ">" in the cell. you do this by taking the contents of the cell and treating it as a String and finding the ">"

This is done in the line beginning arrowPosition. This is the integer value of the position of the ">" in you original string

Next use Left to extract the text up to the ">" and Right to extract the text after the ">"

Then build a new String of rightstr & ">" & leftStr.

Note I input my data from Sheet1 B5 but you can just use any source as long as it is a String in the correct format.

```
Sub Test()

Dim myString As String

myString = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
Debug.Print myString
Debug.Print reverseString(myString)

End Sub


Function reverseString(inputString As String) As String

Dim leftStr As String
Dim rightStr As String
Dim arrowPosition As Integer

arrowPosition = InStr(1, inputString, ">")
leftStr = Left(inputString, arrowPosition - 1)
rightStr = Right(inputString, Len(inputString) - arrowPosition)
reverseString = rightStr & ">" & leftStr

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

just because you look for a VBA, you can add this function into your code:

```
Function rev(t As String) As String
    s = Split(t, ">", 2)
    rev = s(1) & ">" & s(0)
End Function
```

of course only if you have to reverse 2 number, otherwise you'll loop the "s", but the function would lose its usefulness